# object.onsubmit event is not activating

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, quill

first my code, all in one .hbs file:

```
<form id='specialform'>
   <input name='about' type='hidden'>
   <div id='editor'><p>Type something :D</p></div>
    <button type='submit'>Reload</button>
</form>

<script>
var form = document.querySelector('#specialform');
form.onsubmit = function() {

    var about = document.querySelector('input[name=about]');
    about.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());

    console.log('Submitted!');
    console.log('Submitted!', 'Serialized:', $(form).serialize(), 'Serialize Array:', $(form).serializeArray());

    alert('Open Console!');
    return false;
    }
</script>
```

Now when I'm trying to press the submit button while testing, nothing happens instead of the expected console.log(...).
I looked everywhere for an answer, hope you guys can help me. I'm just learning node.js and quilljs and it's pretty difficult.
Thanks for the help. I got the code from this preset https://quilljs.com/playground/#form-submit.

EDIT: Fixed the document.querySelector('specialform') to document.querySelector('#specialform'), still does not work.

EDIT2: Function is now closed with }, just forgot it when copying the code. Problem still persists.

EDIT3:

Made a dummy function:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
    alert('This one works');
    console.log('Submitted!');
    return false;
}
```

Which did NOT work without the return false; statement, but DOES work with it! I changed the original function and included the return, but it still does NOT work sadly.

EDIT4:
I played around with the dummy function some more and have **isolated the problem**.
It stems from this line:

```
console.log('Submitted!', 'Serialized:', $(form).serialize(), 'Serialize Array:', $(form).serializeArray());
```

Can someone tell me why it does not work? :)

One can ignore the problem with that line if one does: function (e) { e.preventDefualt(); ... }, but the change only "goes around"(?) the problem and does not fix it.

EDIT5:
With e.preventDefault() the function works, but there is still no 2nd console.log. So apparently handlebars has a problem with the $(form).serialize(), or I'm just too stupid to see my error. Thanks everyone who helped me anyway!

EDIT6:
ISSUE SOLVED! $.(form).serialize() uses the jquery library which is not that easy to work with in node.js and obviously has to get imported first. I thank everybody who helped me solve it!

Comment: Side note, not related to the answers below, you have a syntax error. You need to close the function with }; right before your </script>

Comment: In #3, instead of `return false`, you're going to want to use `e.preventDefault()`. Was your original issue that your form was submitting and refreshing the page?

Comment: Apparently it did exactly that. I thought it did nothing, but instead it refreshed console + page almost instantly.

Comment: Now it does not refresh the page anymore, still ignores the serialize() console.log tho. Could you explain me why I should not use return false, but instead preventDefault() @mccambridge ? Thanks

Comment: In this case, they have the same effect. But it's good practice to use [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) when you're overriding the default behavior. It's possible you'd have a case where you wanted your function's return value to be `false` and still submit the form. Not in your case, but it's a good idea to learn the standards.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var form = document.querySelector('#specialform');
```

you've missed a hash while using the id selector

Comment: Because I'm using express with handlebars as an engine and some basic logic, I really would like to keep handlebars.

Comment: it should work if you use this to stop the page from reloading  
    "form.onsubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault() ..."=> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpxxvK

Comment: Yes, it does now work, but only because it skips the console.log line with the $(form).serialize(). I thank you very much, but do you know what is wrong with that line. See my 4th edit. :)

Comment: it doesnt skip it, jquery wasnt defined there, now it is and it works as expected => https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpxxvK

Comment: I appreciate your help greatly and I see how it works on your end with html, but it still ignores the second console.log with the serialize() on my end. Only logs the first thing into the console, probably a problem with handlebars..

Comment: it works here fine without the html => https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpxxvK the only difference is that i've commented out the line with quil object as i have it undefined. Are you sure that you have access to the $ jquery object in your code?

Comment: The quill object line works, and commenting it out does not change anything. I do not know what you mean by that I have access to the jquery object, as I have never worked with this $(form) syntax before. How do I know if I have access to it?

Comment: Also I just found out that nothing else behind the faulty serialize() line works if I leave it in. I do not know if this information is useful.

Comment: I've commented the line out as I didn't have the access to the quill object in my demo, if it works in your code that's fine. Regarding jQuery, jQuery is an external library just like handlebars, if you want to use $ object you have to add it to your project first.

Comment: Well that certainly explains it. I feel so stupid now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

`document.querySelector` needs a valid CSS selector.

```
document.querySelector('specialform');
```

is saying, hey JS -- get all specialform elements. If you had `<specialform><!-- content goes here --></specialform>` elements on your page, then that would work.

Instead, you probably want

```
document.querySelector('#specialform');
```

That's saying, hey JS -- get all elements with an ID of `specialform`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var form = document.getElementById('specialform');
```

If you know that you are serching by id than i would use this.
Its faster than query, because it doesnt take care about classes attributes and so on.
And its less error prone if you are unsure about query selectors.
In my opinion the querySelector makes more sense if your structure is more complex.

Comment: Makes sense. I will use your version.